# Changing colour of active links individually in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a navigation menu where each link within it will be a different colour when active. I know you can usually do something like this:

```
.side_bar_nav li.current-menu-item a{
    color: #ff6633;
}
```

But this gives each link the same colour when active I want to target each link individually and give it its own color. This is one of the links I want to target when active, I want to set its active colour to #336699.

```
 <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-49">
  <a href="http://fyberproperty.co.uk/">home</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your li elements have a unique ID, you can use the following:

```
.page-id-9 #menu-item-49 a {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, using :active only applies the colour when the link is clicked and held down. I want it to show when the page for that link is open.

Comment: Oh I understand now. I'm afraid you can't solve that with CSS only unless you have a unique ID per page.

Comment: each page has its own individual class added by wordpress. This particular page has the class of .page-id-9. Would I be able to do it with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work

```
.side_bar_nav li.current-menu-item a{
  color: #ff6633;
}
```

But if this is giving the same color to all link. Are you sure the current link is not a parent menu item.